# Social Login in a multi-site instance

Tags: multilingual, multisite, social-connected

I was able to make the social login work for a single site instance, using just the OOB items and without the need to . The version is Sitecore 8.0 update 5 and also, did not download any module for this.

I used a custom markup (instead of the default rendering) as:

```
<form action="/Social/FacebookConnector/Login" method="post">
 <button type="submit" class="fb-btn">
   <span>
     Sign in with Facebook
   </span>
 </button>     
</form>
```

This was needed, because it is a multi-language site and the author may want to change the button text.

But now, we have a multi site instance and each site will have its own Social Network application.

I created a new one at
`/sitecore/system/Social/Applications/MySite/Facebook-MySite`

How can we tell Sitecore to use this item for *MySite*. Is there a config setting where I can declare this item's ID. I checked the configs in /include/social, but no luck.

I also tried using the default rendering and in the parameters, selecting the new application. It renders a similar markup and has a hidden field which has an encrypted string in its value, which changes on every refresh.

So, how should I go about for achieving a social login with custom Application and custom markup.